keystroke "'" using {control down} not running
When I run this in Final Cut pro, the keystroke "'" using {control down} does not seem to work, I know the code enters the IF statement because of the result.  I also tried,    key code {59, 39}, but no luck.
I am running Sequoia 15.1.1 and I think that Shortcut or Apple script need to be added to automation under "privacy and security" to allow the apple script system event, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.  PLEASE HELP!
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events"
        set activeApp to name of application processes whose frontmost is true
    end tell
    if activeApp = {"Final Cut Pro"} then
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "'" using {control down}
        end tell
        return "Next Marker ran"
    else
        return "Open FCPX"
    end if
end run


System Events is a background application located in the /System/Library/CoreServices/ folder, and can be added to the Accessibility list by dragging the app into the list or by navigating to it after pressing the + button.
